# HTML\PHP : Flash Player detection technique

Tags: php, html, flash

when we place flash files in our websites, it OFF-COURSE requires flash player on client machines,  and prompts to install flash player...

is there some php code using which i can check weather there is flash player on the client machine and if not then instead of placing\embedding a flash file i place an images over there...

cuz in my specific case flash is not that much important... it is just for cosmetics, an animation... which i can replace by a gif or a simple jpeg doesnot matter...

but can i do it

Comment: Updated my answer with a code example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) can help with this.

You can just place the content to be shown if flash cannot be displayed in the code where the flash object should be, and point the script to it.

In code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>TestFlash</title>

    <!--import the swfobject library /-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <!--Define which div (by ID) gets replaced if flash is present /-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "flash1", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>We are testing some flash</h1>
    <hr />

    <div id="flash1">
        <!-- This stuff will show if flash is not present on the machine  /-->
        <img src="/img/image1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <hr />
    <h2>this is a footer</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805138/html-php-flash-player-detection-technique/3805936#3805936

Answer (score 1):

See this article - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/fp8_detection.html

Adobe have got this sorted now so you can present alternative content / direct users to install flash / detect which version of flash user has and then install latest version if needed from your website without having to visit adobe site.

A little bit of work to get this in place so depends on how important it is that user is using flash or if the alternative content would work just as well. but for delivering flash content and being sure that the user will have correct version installed the Flash Detection Kit works great.

Comment: ... I re-read your question and while my suggestion is good for detecting flash version is probably overkill for your situation. I would look at using swfobject as suggested by powertieke - ive voted that answer up.

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805138/html-php-flash-player-detection-technique/3805936#3805936

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<?
// Search through the HTTP_ACCEPT header for the Flash Player MIME type.
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/x-shockwave-flash'))
{
$hasFlash = true;
}

if ($hasFlash)
{
        // EMBED
} else {
       // IMG
};

?>
```

Comment: And this will work how? Where and how is `$hasFlash` defined?